# Is the GST credit any higher than usual starting July 2010?

Tags: canada, gst, hst, gst-credit

I've heard through the grapevine that starting July 2010 GST credit cheques will be higher than usual because of this new HST? Does anyone have a confirmed answer to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The **GST/HST credit** is a *federal* program meant to offset some or all of the GST or federal portion of the HST.  The amounts are *not* increasing due to Ontario or B.C. introducing HST.  The amounts are the same for all Canadians irrespective of province.

However, the GST/HST credit is still increasing, *slightly*, due to inflation.  Here's a link to the [schedule of the GST/HST credit payment amounts](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/gsthst/gstc_pymnts-eng.html).  Note the individual amount increases from **$248** to **$250**.

However, **Ontario is introducing the new [Ontario Sales Tax Credit](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/stc/index.html)**.  Perhaps that's what you heard about?  There's also a list of [OSTC Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/stc/faq.html).  Note in particular:

> **The [Ontario Sales Tax] credit is a
>   non-taxable quarterly payment that
>   will be issued separately from the
>   GST/HST credit payments.**

Answer (score 0):

The 250 is for for a single person per year so the total of the 4 payments which would be 62.50 for a married person the benifit amount is 500 a year (4 payments) which equals 4 payments of 125 =500 I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

If you havent done so, open an account at cra.gc.ca/myaccount for all payment dates and scheduled payments. I checked my account and my July GST payment was 175.75 and the October, January and Arpil payments are 285 each!!